# 2 operator overload functions of the same type

Tags: kotlin

I'm doing [Kotlin Koans's Operator Overloading](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Conventions/Operators%20overloading/Task.kt) exercise and am wondering how the compiler chooses which `MyDate.plus()` function to use:

```
import TimeInterval.*
import java.util.Calendar

data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int)

enum class TimeInterval { DAY, WEEK, YEAR }

operator fun MyDate.plus(timeInterval: TimeInterval) = addTimeIntervals(timeInterval, 1)

class FullTimeInterval(val timeInterval: TimeInterval, val number: Int) 
operator fun TimeInterval.times(number: Int) = FullTimeInterval(this, number)

operator fun MyDate.plus(timeIntervals: FullTimeInterval) 
= addTimeIntervals(timeIntervals.timeInterval, timeIntervals.number)

fun task1(today: MyDate): MyDate {
    return today + YEAR + WEEK 
}

fun task2(today: MyDate): MyDate {
    return today + YEAR * 2 + WEEK * 3 + DAY * 5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two classes: `TimeInterval` and `FullTimeInterval` and two overloaded functions:
`MyDate.plus(timeIntervals: TimeInterval)` and `MyDate.plus(timeIntervals: FullTimeInterval)`

The compiler knows the type of the argument and it selects the closest function by the signature. The decision is made at the compilation time and depends on the computed types of the arguments.

You may find more information on that at
https://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#overload-resolution

Comment: I think I understand now - it will be determined whether a `FullTimeInterval` will be passed (TIME * 2) or `TimeInterval` (TIME)